# User location in macOS with Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, location

I found this example here: [How to get user location ? [macOS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554220/how-to-get-user-location-macos)

The OP was asking about get user location, basically the coordinates. Other code I found with the user also asking for a solution was here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93215

In both case, besides they won´t work, the people who reply says to set up user permission, in my case I dont see or have the Info.plist file, and yes I am a noob with macOS dev and all these stuff of Swift.

In a nutshell, I just would need to know how to get the coordinates, if available with a macOS.