# Setting map along with user current location for osx

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, mapkit

Greeting pros,

As I know we can make a map by using google map api for IOS like the code below here.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
/* For cocoa:
   Import Cocoa
   Import MapKit
*/
   class ViewController: NSViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var didFindMyLocation = false
var strForCurLatitude = "";
var strForCurLongitude = "";
var currentLocation = locManager.location!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        print("User allowed us to access location")
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error while get location \(error)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation? = locationManager.location
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = location?.coordinate
    print(coordinate!)
    print(coordinate!.latitude)
    print(coordinate!.longitude)
    strForCurLatitude = "\(coordinate!.latitude)"
    strForCurLongitude = "\(coordinate!.longitude)"
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate!.latitude, longitude: coordinate!.longitude, zoom: 15)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate!.latitude, coordinate!.longitude)
    marker.map = mapView
}


override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
}
```

But when I tried the similar method for osx (*The difference is that I am using mapkit instead of google map*), it says **requestWhenInUseAuthorization()' is unavailable**. I red this thread [How to get user location ? [macOS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554220/how-to-get-user-location-macos) but it seems goes without clear resolved whether it is available to get current location for osx or not. So is it inaccessible to get current location for macOS/cocoa app? If it is not, then how to get current location in cocoa app?

I am pretty sure that many xcode programmers like me tried to solve this problem. Any answer you will get big appreciation tho. :)

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong @Willeke, because what I try to achieve here is not authorization for macos instead **user/device current location**. In addition, without requestWhenInUseAuthorization() the output of location?.coordinate whether it is coordinate!.latitude or coordinate!.longitude is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` *is* unavailable on macOS.

Here's the source for a NSViewController subclass that checks for location manager and the current location successfully in Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.13.6:

```
import Cocoa
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: NSViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
                        didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("location manager auth status changed to:" )
        switch status {
            case .restricted:
                print("status restricted")
            case .denied:
                print("status denied")

        case .authorized:
                print("status authorized")
                let location = locationManager.location
                print("location: \(String(describing: location))")

            case .authorizedAlways:
                print("status authorized always")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("status not yet determined")
        }


    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
                            didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print( "location manager failed with error \(error)" )
    }
}
```

works for me on macOS if you say yes to the "enable location services" prompt when you launch the app the first time.

Note you also need the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` property list entry as indicated in the documentation.

console output is (slightly obfuscated):

> location manager auth status changed to: status not yet determined
>   location manager auth status changed to: status authorized location:
>   Optional(<+4X.48,-12X.62632228> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps /
>   course -1.00) @ 11/3/18, 11:42:48 AM Pacific Daylight Time)

Comment: I have provided an updated version of this answer (macOS 10.14.6 & Xcode 11.2.1, Swift 5.1) here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554220/how-to-get-user-location-macos/53134473#53134473